# Phaser inside iframe, keyboard input stops working after cavas/iframe has lost focus

Tags: javascript, iframe, phaser-framework

I'm working on a [Phaser CE](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce) game which supports both mouse/touch input and keyboard input to do various actions.

The problem is; the game is running **inside an iframe** and the keyboard input works correctly until the canvas loses focus. The game pauses which is correct behaviour, then I click inside canvas again, game continues and mouse input still works. But now the keyboard input is not working anymore. When the game is not running inside an iframe this is not a problem, the keyboard continues to work after losing focus, pausing and then continuing.

Do I have to use something other than "game.input.keyboard.addCallbacks" to check for keyboard input? Below is the minimum code to reproduce this issue.

```
m﻿ygame.GameState.prototype = {

    create: function() {
        this.stage.backgroundColor = "#f0f";
        this._levelindex = 0;
        // ..
        // etc.

        // game input for mouse and keyboard
        this.game.input.onDown.add(this.onGameMouseDown, this); // mouse/touch
        this.game.input.keyboard.addCallbacks(this, this.doGameKeyInput, null, null); // keyboard
        // ..
    },

    onGameMouseDown: function(evt) {
        // code.. ok works fine
    },

    doGameKeyInput: function(key) {
        var kc = key.keyCode;
        var action = 0;
        if (kc == 32) {action = 1}; // space
        if (kc﻿ == 90) {action = 2}; // Z
        if (kc == 88) {action = 3}; // X
        // etc. this works until canvas loses focus
    }﻿
}﻿
```

Also, I've created a page to isolate and reproduce this issue, see [keyboard test](http://bdrgames.nl/testkeyboard/).

Comment: Looks like when you change the focus of the keyboard, its never return to the 
 iframe's canvas context, only work when you set the focus first in the iframe's canvas, see [this](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC/issues/506#issuecomment-134302378). Maybe you need a callback to set the focus manually... If you try in the console with `$('iframe').contentWindow.focus()` you get the focus again...

Comment: I just noticed that manually setting the focus back to the canvas using the TAB button does work. In the "keyboard test" page (see post), press the "do something" button, then close the alert pop-up, then press TAB once and the focus is back on the canvas and keyboard events work again.

However, I expected a mouse-click inside the canvas should also realise this focus again, but this is not the case. I don't expect the average player to know this or figure this out, so how can I realise this?